# How do I Include IPTC metadata for rights usage terms in a JPEG exported from Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom, metadata, export, windows-10

I have a metadata preset I created in Lightroom which I use to import JPG files from my camera. In this preset, I provide a text value for the "Rights Usage Terms" attribute in the metadata. I can see the text while in Lightroom as shown here:

[image]

but when I right click the image in Lightroom and export I do not see the "Rights Usage Terms "attribute in the exported file properties under Windows 10. Below is a picture of the export settings I have for metadata when I export the files:

[image]

Is there a way to get Lightroom to include the "Rights Usage Terms" attribute in the exported file under Windows 10? I am using Adobe Lightroom Classic 10.2 Release.

Comment: Perhaps this `https://digital-photography-school.com/lightroom-add-your-iptc-metadata-on-import/` will help.

Answer (score 2):

According to the article which qrk listed in the comments area the "Rights Usage Terms" property along with other properties may not be visible to all applications under Windows 10.  I do not see this property when viewing file information under Windows Explorer. However, I do see it if I open the file with Adobe Photoshop. There is a placeholder for this property in Adobe Illustrator but the data that was exported with Lightroom is not seen there either. I have added the information to the copyright attribute. Some of the data is seen in Illustrator but part of it is truncated off.  It appears the full set of data can only be seen by Adobe Photoshop.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to get Lightroom to include the "Rights Usage Terms"
> attribute in the exported file under Windows 10?

Lightroom **is** including that data.  The problem is that Windows will not read and display every possible piece of metadata in a file.  It will only displayed what is in the Properties->Details tab, of which the data will be filled from a variety of different embedded tags.  The [`XMP-xmpRights:UsageTerms`](https://www.iptc.org/std/photometadata/specification/IPTC-PhotoMetadata#rights-usage-terms), which is where LR stores this data, is not one of them.